# Is there a way to selectively apply timestamps in mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently designing a mongoose Schema. The schema is for blog comments, it looks like this:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  commentedOn: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  contents:{
    type: String
  },
  points: {
    type: Number,
    default:0
  },
  timestamps: true
})
```

The points field is to record the votes of one comment. I don't want to change the timestamp every time when users vote the comment. Is there a way to achieve this? Or should I move the points field out of this schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `timestamps` should be passed in the [second argument of the schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps).

Regarding your question, the only way I can think of doing this is to not use `timestamps` and explicitly declare your timestamp fields e.g. `createdAt` and `updatedAt` in your schema. Whenever you save or update, you would explicitly set the `updatedAt` field (or not) depending on the situation.

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    commentedOn: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    contents: String,
    points: { Number, default: 0 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updatedAt: Date
});
```

Comment: I think this is what you said, but for others, to be clear you can send in `updatedAt` as one of the values in your update record (and if you grab `updateAt` from your existing object then it'll be the same). I.e., explicitly declaring the `updateAt` field overwrites MongoDB's autoupdate